# Set a close icon in the top right on camera scanner using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this .scss code:

```
.closed{
    padding: .5rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid rgb(53, 52, 52);
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: -1rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    z-index: 100;
    box-sizing: initial;
}
```

and this html code:

```
<mat-dialog-actions align="right">
    <button class="closed" (click)=closed()>X</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
<mat-dialog-content>
    <div id="interactive" class="viewport">
    </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

On here I have two problems, first with responsivity, my video doesn't work correctly in some devices. And second Closed button I want to put in top right no in top left . [image]

Can you share with me any idea how to fix issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

If it doesn't work try putting `position:relative` on mat-dialog-actions